# Wp_query doesn't work inside a php file for ajax call (return 500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to display a Custom Post Type (espositori) post's with ajax when i select a dropdown's menu voice from select.

Inside file1.php i have this code:

```
<select id="tipologia-cliente" name="cpt" onchange="showVariables(this.value)">
  // some options
</select>
```

and the ajax script is

```
<script>
function showVariables(str) {
  var xhttp;
  if (str.length == 0) { 
    document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/wp-content/themes/TemplateName/templates-page/getcpt.php?q="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
</script>
```

---

Inside the getcpt.php File the code is:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'espositori',
    'numberposts' => -1
);

$myquery = new WP_Query( $args );

if($myquery->have_posts()):
    while($myquery->have_posts()):
        $myquery->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo '<br>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();   
endif;
```

When i'm select one option, i receive this error on console
GET https://www.mysite.it/wp-content/themes/mysite/templates-page/getcpt.php?q=espositori 500 (Internal Server Error)

If i replace the getcpt.php code with a simple echo "Hello World!", this work...

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks so much

Comment: Great, you have a 500 error, meaning your exact problem will be in the `error_log`

Comment: And what would be the solution?

Comment: Firstly, to let us know what the actual error message is. Look in your log!

Comment: You cannot directly run a theme file like this since WordPress will not get initialized. You can try WordPress AJAX method - do you need the code?

Comment: @delboy1978uk oh sorry, i'm just frustrated about this error.. on error_log i have this error:
error:  Class 'WP_Query' not found in /var/www/vhosts/mysite/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/mysite/templates-page/getcpt.php on line 10\n', referer: https://www.mysite/my-page/

Comment: @OutsourceWordPress yes please, if you have the code can you post it? Thanks

Comment: You need to find where the file for that class is, and use `require_once '/path/to/Whatever.php';`

Comment: Check my answer below and let me know.

Comment: It’s because you are “doing AJAX wrong” to begin with, at least by WP conventions … you should not put script files just anywhere on the server and call them on your own, forgoing WordPress. The proper way would be to add this via `wp_ajax_my_action` _inside_ of WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code using WordPress AJAX.

Add this to **functions.php**:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_load_custom_espositori', 'load_custom_espositori_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_custom_espositori', 'load_custom_espositori_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}

function load_custom_espositori_ajax_handler() {      
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'espositori',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );

    $myquery = new WP_Query( $args );

    if($myquery->have_posts()):
        while($myquery->have_posts()):
            $myquery->the_post();
            the_title();
            echo '<br>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_query();   
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
```

Add this to **Template File**:

```
<script>
function showVariables(str) {
    var xhttp;
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        jQuery('#main-content').html('');
        return;
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // AJAX handler
        data : { action : 'load_custom_espositori', qry : str },
        type : 'POST',
        success : function( $result ){
            if( $result ) {
                jQuery('#main-content').html($result);
            }
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Let me know the WordPress version if not works.

Comment: Thanks for the code! 
I'll try it in next hours and i'll check you!

Comment: Ok i'll tryed it and work perfectly!!! Thanks alot!!! 
Now i have another problem... What if i select the CPT name from option select? From your code i can't understand how i can use value from <option> like a varaible and set it in 'post_type' query

Comment: What are you trying to achieve while changing the dropdown? You need another custom post type to load?

Comment: I have to create a filter selection with Select drop down menu. 
At first i want to choose che CPT to show by drop down menu, then i have to create more select to filter by ACF field. 
But first i want to understand how simple filtering with variable work.
Like, if i had <select name="cpt-name"><option  value="cpt1">CPT 1</option><option value="cpt2>CPT 2</option></section> how this work with your code?

Comment: Now the dropdown value passed to AJAX via 'qry' variable (`data : { action : 'load_custom_espositori', qry : str }`) and if you just want to load different custom post type data, just replace `'post_type' => 'espositori',` with `'post_type' => $_REQUEST['qry'],` in 'functions.php'. You can just have the custom post type names in your dropdown.

Comment: Yes! I just tryed by myself and it's work! 
Now i read your answer and i did the same things! Now i think i can go with my code! 

Last thing! Due to not write alot of code inside the function.php file, can i write the code inside function load_custom_espositori_ajax_handler() in a .php file and call it with a require  inside that function?

Thank very very very much!

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to add this to your 'functions.php' - `require_once ( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/filename.php' );`

Comment: I just wanna cry!!! I did it and got again 500 internal server error... 
on function.php i have 
/*-------------------*/
add_action('wp_ajax_load_custom_espositori', 'load_custom_espositori_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_custom_espositori', 'load_custom_espositori_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}

function load_custom_espositori_ajax_handler() {
 require_once( THEME_PATH . '/inc/ajax/ajax-filter-system.php' );
}
/*-----------------*/
Inside ajax-filter-system.php there is all the code with $_POST and WP_Query, but i get again 500 error

Comment: Don't be panic. Just check the server's error log and let me know the exact error.

Comment: I get this message:
PHP Warning:  require_once(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/mysiste/functions.php on line 792\nPHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(https://www.mysite.it/wp-content/themes/mysiste/inc/ajax/ajax-filter-system.php): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/mysiste/functions.php on line 792\n

Comment: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'https://www.mysite.it/wp-content/themes/mysiste/inc/ajax/ajax-filter-system.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/vhosts/mysite.it/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/mysiste/functions.php on line 792\n', referer: https://www.mysite.it/mypage

Comment: Where is your new PHP file located? My previous code assumes 'inc' folder inside your theme folder.

Comment: the path of new PHP file is 
https://www.mysite.it/wp-content/themes/mysytetheme/inc/ajax/ajax-filter-system.php

Comment: You added wrong function - look at my original comment, replace `THEME_PATH` with `get_stylesheet_directory()`.

Comment: Yeah!! Now work all fine!!! THEME_PATH assume get_stylesheet_directory_uri() and i haven't read that you said get_stylesheet_directory()!! 
Now seem work all fine! Hope i will not have problem with filter sistem! 
Thanks very very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. As you need to set post limit, the attribute is `posts_per_page`. WP_Query [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'espositori',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
global $post;
$myquery = new WP_Query( $args );

if($myquery->have_posts()):
    while($myquery->have_posts()):
        $myquery->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo '<br>';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();   
endif;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tryed but isn't the solution. 
The query inside a normale php page work fine.

Comment: Have u added `global $post;`

Answer (score 0):

Try using $wpdb global object instead. Here's an example from your code:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'espositori',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
);
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_posts($args);

if(!empty($posts)){
  foreach($posts as $post){
  setup_postdata($post); 
  //You can use the_title() the_content() the_excerpt() the_permalink() etc...
  echo get_the_title($post->ID);
  echo '<br />';
}
}
```

---

Hope that helps!